# Problem with launching emulator from Android Studio - AVD Pixel_XX_XXX_28 is already running

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I have a problem when I launch an emulator from Android Studio. It shows the following message:

> Error while waiting for device: AVD Pixel_XL_API_28 is already running.
>
> If that is not the case, delete the files at
> `C:\Users\user\.android\avd\Pixel_XL_API_28.avd\*.lock`
> and try again.

I saw another solution on StackOverflow, which said to delete the file from `Emulator.avd\*.lock`. But here is my problem, as I can't delete the file: `The action can't be completed because the file is open in qemu-system-x86_64`.

If I stop the emulator, the file with .lock extension is removed.

Thanks for solutions!

Comment: Try to run it on another emulator(maybe the one that you were using was not downloaded properly)

Answer (score 0):

The question was asked long ago but if anyone stumbles upon this.

Just Delete the files and directories in `..\.android\avd\<your_avd_name>\` which ends with `.lock`

Answer (score -1):

emulators are stressful, use your real android device or download genymotion